# tomcat server eclipse localhost8080 is working but 404 in project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat

I have tomcat server v7.0 in eclipse IDE and the server is running smooth when you visit the **http://localhost:8080** but in my own personal page **http://localhost:8080/ch7sunrise/** is not working and getting an error of 404, I check the logs in tomcat it shows `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Oct/2017:07:55:00 +0800] "GET /ch7sunrise/ HTTP/1.1" 404 973` am I missing something and anyone can help me on this one?

Comment: Post your mapping or some code and configuration

Comment: done adding the images

Comment: Why do not let Eclipse do the deploying for you?